# Make a grid responsive to its parent width

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I have an HTML structure like this:

```html
    <div class="row">
      <div class="half-row">
         <div class="cell">
           ..content..
         </div>
         <div class="cell">
           ..content..
         </div>
         <div class="cell">
           ..content..
         </div>
         <div class="cell">
           ..content..
         </div>
         <div class="cell">
           ..content..
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="half-row">
         <div class="cell">
           ..content..
         </div>
         <div class="cell">
           ..content..
         </div>
         <div class="cell">
           ..content..
         </div>
         <div class="cell">
           ..content..
         </div>
         <div class="cell">
           ..content..
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
```

where class 'row' has width: 100% of its parent and the parent width will change over time.

My goal is that the two divs with a "half-row" class must be in-line and occupy 50% of the "row" div. If the size of the "row" div goes below 640px (so the half-row will be < 320px) the two half-row class divs have to stack and each of them occupies 100% of the available space.
In both cases, the internal div ("cell" class) must equally divide the available space.

Every suggestion is welcome. Thank you

Comment: Have you experimented with flexboxes? It would be polite to show your own efforts. Now it looks like you want somebody else to create your project.
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: @Daniel, You're right and I'm already trying with flexbox but I have no experience with it. My request for suggestions is aimed at those who can direct me on which properties of flexbox to use and how to set them. I will add to the question the few lines of css with my first attempt. Thank you for the link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@S.C. is right, flexbox is the way to go and I would also recommend reading the [CSS-tricks article](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)! In fact I have used this very same article to construct this alternative example, that's independent of the screen-width:

```css
.row, .half-row {
  display: flex;
}

.row {
  width: 100%;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.half-row {
  width: 320px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  justify-content: space-around;

  /* for seeing better what's going on */
  background-color: #aaa;
  border: 1px solid #333;
}
```

```html
 <div class="row">
      <div class="half-row">
         <div class="cell">
           ..content..
         </div>
         <div class="cell">
           ..content..
         </div>
         <div class="cell">
           ..content..
         </div>
         <div class="cell">
           ..content..
         </div>
         <div class="cell">
           ..content..
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="half-row">
         <div class="cell">
           ..content..
         </div>
         <div class="cell">
           ..content..
         </div>
         <div class="cell">
           ..content..
         </div>
         <div class="cell">
           ..content..
         </div>
         <div class="cell">
           ..content..
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: Now that works like a charm! Can you explain me why do you overwrite half-row width?

Comment: That was actually leftover from trying different solutions earlier and had nothing to do with the final solution! I edited the code to reflect that. The key really is to give it the `width` you want to break at and then let it grow if it has more space using `flex-grow: 1`

Comment: TNX a lot, it works perfectly, last question: class "cell" elements are flex-box item, so eventually can I make them grow differently without affecting the row/half-row layout?

Comment: Sure that is absolutely possible. Check out [this codepen](https://codepen.io/luke-codewalker/pen/GXKgoP?editors=0100) for an example.

Comment: I wish more people upvote this. I haven't find better solutions to the same problem(resize based on parent, not screen).

Answer (score 1):

You can use flexbox for that.
See excellent article from [Css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) about Flexbox

If you want to tell us more about the cell class who need to divide the available space "equally" (Horizontally ? Vertically ? both ? Squared ? etc.) I'll update my code to fit with your needs.

I Hope this could help you.

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.half-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row; /* or column */
  flex-basis: 100%;
  
  /* remove after tests */
  background-color: red;
  height: 500px;
}

.cell {
  flex-basis: 100%;

  /* remove after tests */
  background-color: blue; 
}

@media screen and (min-width: 640px) {
  .half-row { flex-basis: 50%; }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="half-row">
         <div class="cell">
           ..content..
         </div>
         <div class="cell">
           ..content..
         </div>
         <div class="cell">
           ..content..
         </div>
         <div class="cell">
           ..content..
         </div>
         <div class="cell">
           ..content..
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="half-row">
         <div class="cell">
           ..content..
         </div>
         <div class="cell">
           ..content..
         </div>
         <div class="cell">
           ..content..
         </div>
         <div class="cell">
           ..content..
         </div>
         <div class="cell">
           ..content..
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, the elements with "cell" class must divide the space equally horizontally. I see you've used a media query but 640px is not the screen size, but the container div with the "row" class size. This container is used in various parts of the page with different dimensions (it has "width: 100%") and I would like that if the element that contains it has a dimension > 640px the two "half-row" are aligned, otherwise they will be one above the other